# How can I stop the password field being pre-populated on edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, webforms, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have this problem all the time in my rails apps and I still need the correct solution. Whenever a user edits their own record the password field is being populated. I suspect its Firefox as setting @user.password = nil in the edit action doesn't help.

The problem is the password confirmation isn't populated so validation fails due to a miss-match.

I've tried the following:

```
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, :value => "", :autofill => false, :class => 'max' %>
```

But that doesn't do it. I've also tried `:autofill => 'off'` which doesn't work either.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set autocomplete="off" in the form and the input tags

```
<form name="blah" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: In Ruby for copy and paste lazy people like me:
<%= form_for(user, :html => { autocomplete: "off" }) do |f| %>

Comment: This solution does not work with old browsers, like ie7 or ie8

Comment: This doesn't work for me (chrome 47.0) but for more details see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 2):

The line `f.password_field :password, :value => ''` didn't work for me (on rails 3.1). Although I coud empty the field with `f.password_field :password, :value => nil`.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. tell firefox not to fill those fields;
2. give password field a different name from "password".

Comment: 1. I cannot control the user. 2. Great idea which I'm sure would work, however I would have to modify the password field in quite a few projects, some with AuthLogic, some with RA etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML options are in their own hash so the syntax should look like this

```
<%= f.password_field :password, { :value => '' } %>
```

This should replace the value attribute in the response HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response although the syntax is perfectly valid as it is. The list of parameters after the method are still a hash without or without the brackets. Look at these examples: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/password_field

Comment: When last parameter is an hash, brackets are optional; neither mandatory nor forbidden.

Comment: True enough, thanks for pointing out my own syntactic hangup. The :value => '' should be all that is needed though.

Comment: Thank you! This should be marked as the correct answer (for Rails 3.2.x), because RoR's built in `<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %> ... ` does not accept `:autocomplete => "off"` directives.

Answer (score 0):

As a field option, you can pass it like this

```
<%= f.password_field :password, {:autocomplete =>"off"}  %>
```